# Page View Counter Account

Tags: salesforce, counter

I have created a new custom field **CounterAcc** at the object **Account** to count the page view of each account.
Below you will find my code, but I get an **Error DML requires SObject or SObject list type: Integer**.

I don't know if this is the right way to create a page view counter, I read a lot about the actionpoller, but I'm not familiar with the action function.

Thanks,
peX

EDIT 31.10.14:
I edited a bit the code, but I still get the same error. :-(

```apex
public class TestCounter2 {

    private Id accId {get; set;}
    public TestCounter2 (ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) {
        accId = stdcontroller.getRecord().Id;
    }

    public Integer CounterAcc {get; set;}

    public void incCount() {

       FOR (Account acc : [SELECT CounterAcc__c FROM Account WHERE Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId]; {
          Acc.CounterAcc__c++;
       }

       IF(!CounterAcc.isEmpty()) {
          UPDATE ConterAcc;
       }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Update `Account Object` but you are updating `ConterAcc` which is a `Integer Property`.

```
UPDATE ConterAcc;
```

Update the Account Object.